# En la página de elecciones vía móvil, el texto de la primera nominación sale en una columna diminuta

Tags: bug, elecciones, diseño, web-móvil

Al abrir la [página de elecciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/election) con el móvil veo que la primera nominación sale toda ella en una columna diminuta:

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
>
> <sub>clicad en la imagen para verla entera</sub>

Por contra, el resto de candidaturas sí salen bien.

Comment: Confirmo que eso es así en mi lado (Chrome en Android)

Comment: En Safari de iPhone también se ve así

Comment: confirmado... y ademas si te llega un mensaje a tu postulacion (lo que me ocurre a mi), la app tira error porque no sabe a donde dirigirte